# Underscore GroupBy Sort

Tags: node.js, sorting, functional-programming, underscore.js

I have a question regarding programming in function style.

I use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library.

Let's consider some use-case. I have an array of some labels with repetitions I need to count how many occurrences of each label is in array and sort it according to the number of occurrences.

For counting, how many labels I can use countBy

```
_.countBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(num) {
  return num % 2 == 0 ? 'even': 'odd';
});
=> {odd: 3, even: 2}
```

But here, as result I have a hash, which doesn't have meaning for order, so there is no sort. So here, I need to convert the hash to array then to sort it and convert backward to hash.

I am pretty sure there is an elegant way to do so, however I am not aware of it.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sort it and convert backward to hash.

No, that would loose the order again.

You could use

```
var occurences = _.countBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(num) {
  return num % 2 == 0 ? 'even': 'odd';
});
// {odd: 3, even: 2}
var order = _.sortBy(_.keys(occurences), function(k){return occurences[k];})
// ["even", "odd"]
```

or maybe just

```
_.sortBy(_.pairs(occurences), 1)
// [["even", 2], ["odd", 3]]
```

Comment: I wonder if you can advise some manual, textbook with these functional programming tricks.

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html (one of the few tutorials that I know and can recommend) has a short introduction, but doesn't help with the tricks. I've only learnt them by everyday practice, and 2 years of experience with Haskell :-)